# I Have An Issue In Grid View Builder

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-apk

[without building apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccbJc.jpg)
when i dont build apk in flutter this type of gridview is build
and when i build apk this type of gridveiw list build in flutter
[when apk is build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXrQE.jpg)

this is my code i want to build an apk so any one can fix this issue
i am getting this issue
while building an app in flutter
otherwise it is ok and give no issue but when i build this app i got error like this is gridview.builder and listview .builder also and i am using scaffold and in body i try everything but nothing work

here is my code

```
  body: SafeArea(
child: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
child: Column(
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
children: [
  Text('Select Your City'),
  Expanded(child: GridView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
    itemCount: serviceDataList.length,
    itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
      // print(serviceDataList);
      return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() async {
            if(isRedundentClick(DateTime.now())){
              Fluttertoast.showToast(
                msg: "hold on, processing",
                toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
                timeInSecForIosWeb: 1,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 16.0,
              );
              return;
            }else{
              SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
              prefs.setString('City_Id', serviceDataList[i]['city_id']);
              prefs.setString('City_Name', serviceDataList[i]['city_name']);
              prefs.setString('City_Lat', serviceDataList[i]['city_lat']);
              prefs.setString('City_Long', serviceDataList[i]['city_long']);
              print(serviceDataList[i]['city_id']);
              print(serviceDataList[i]['city_name']);
              int? rowsEffected2 = await dbHelper?.deletecart();
              print(rowsEffected2);
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>Navigation()));
            }
          });
        },
        child: Card(
            elevation: 4,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 210,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                              // minHeight: 35.0,
                              maxHeight: 200.0,
                            ),
                            child: Expanded(
                              child: Image.network(
                                serviceDataList[i]['city_img'] ?? '',
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          // Row(
                          //   children: [
                          //     Text(
                          //       'Subtitle',
                          //       style: TextStyle(
                          //         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          //         fontSize: 15,
                          //       ),
                          //     ),
                          //   ],
                          // )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 35,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade300,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        serviceDataList[i]['city_name'],
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
        ),
      );
    },
    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      childAspectRatio: 1.0,
      crossAxisSpacing: 5,
      mainAxisSpacing: 5,
      mainAxisExtent: 264,
    ),
  ),)
])))
    // bottomNavigationBar:Row(
    //   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    //   children: [
    //     SizedBox(
    //         height: 40,
    //         width: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/1.5),
    //         child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: (){Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=> HomePage()),);
    //         }, child: Text('Save'))),
    //   ],
    // )
);
```

pls help me with this code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid wrapping your image within an Expanded widget when the parent is a ConstrainedBox. This is because the parent of the expanded widget cannot be a ConstrainedBox, which is an incorrect use of the parent widget. In debug mode, this will only display a warning, but in release mode, it will not render correctly.

Replace this:

```
   ConstrainedBox(
                        constraints: new BoxConstraints(
                          // minHeight: 35.0,
                          maxHeight: 200.0,
                        ),
                        child: Expanded(
                          child: Image.network(
                            serviceDataList[i]['city_img'] ?? '',
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
```

With this:

```
ConstrainedBox(
     constraints:
           new BoxConstraints(
                   maxHeight: 200.0,
                   ),
                child: Image.network(
                      serviceDataList[i]['city_img'] ?? '',
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      ),
            ),
```

Comment: Still facing That error

Comment: I saw that you were also using Expanded to Wrap your GridViewBuilder. could you try removing that and check again?